# PHP URL Encoding / Decoding

Tags: php, url, url-encoding

I used the solution accepted for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt) for encrypting by id for example in **/index.php?id=3** . The problem is I cannot send the encrypted value as an url, example **/index.php?id=dsf13f3343f23/23=**. Because sometimes it will have weird characters in the url e.g. notice the `=` sign in the end

Comment: @Michael J.V. : Would like to encode the key to stop people from crawling our data by looping through the ids. Whats wrong with it? Whats the best / better solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *weird characters* in the values passed in the URL should be escaped, using [**`urlencode(`**](http://php.net/urlencode)).

For example, the following portion of code :

```
echo urlencode('dsf13f3343f23/23=');
```

would give you :

```
dsf13f3343f23%2F23%3D
```

Which works fine, as an URL parameter.

And if you want to build aquery string with several parameters, take a look at the [**`http_build_query()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function.

For example :

```
echo http_build_query(array(
    'id' => 'dsf13f3343f23/23=',
    'a' => 'plop',
    'b' => '$^@test', 
));
```

will give you :

```
id=dsf13f3343f23%2F23%3D&a=plop&b=%24%5E%40test
```

This function deals with escaping and concatenating the parameters itself ;-)

Comment: Hey Pascal! may i ask you a simple question
when we have an encoded url with characters like ' it gives us %27, now is there any security concerns about these percent numbers?? or any other problems with url encoding besides that the %27 looks very ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Use PHP's [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to encode the value before you put it into a URL.

> `string` **`urlencode`** `( string` *`$str`* `)`
>   This function is convenient when
>   encoding a string to be used in a
>   query part of a URL, as a convenient
>   way to pass variables to the next
>   page.

This function converts "weird" characters, such as `=`, into a format safe to put into a URL. You can use it like this:

```
Header('Location: /index.php?id=' . urlencode($id))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use Base64 to encode the binary value for the URL, there is also a [variant with URL and filename safe alphabet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5).

You can use the [`strtr` function](http://php.net/strtr) to translate one from alphabet to the other:

```
$base64url = strtr($base64, '+/', '-_');
$base64 = strtr($base64url, '-_', '+/');
```

So you can use these functions to encode and decode *base64url*:

```
function base64url_encode($str) {
    return strtr(base64_encode($str), '+/', '-_'));
}
function base64url_decode($base64url) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($base64url, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

See also [my answer on *What is a good way to produce an short alphanumeric string from a long md5 hash?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314113/php-what-is-a-good-way-to-produce-an-short-alphanumeric-string-from-a-long-md5/3316628#3316628)

Comment: I've implemented this so many times and seems to be easiest way (if you still want to go this route).

Comment: @Gumbo There is an extra closing parenthesis in your base64url_encode function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no use in encrypting parameters.
Send it as is:

```
/index.php?id=3
```

nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Unless you are using a social security number or something similar as a primary key.

Comment: should you use it as a primary key at all?

Comment: I'm sure there are some applications where it might be useful.