# how to send a variable in url

Tags: php

```
http://foo.com?url= [  http://foo2.com?thing=blah   ]
```

I want the whole url with the $thing variable to be stored in $url .

NOTE: the bracket are just to make clear.

Comment: Looks like a job for [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: There are a lot of similar questions already on SO. I'd suggest using sessions to pass your URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP URL Encoding / Decoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662249/php-url-encoding-decoding)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode):

```
$param = urlencode('http://foo2.com?thing=blah')
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you seen [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) (also to be combined with [`http_build_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php))?

```
$data = array(
  'url' => 'ttp://foo2.com?thing=blah'
);
$url = 'http://foo.com?' . http_build_query($data);
```

*Note: These require `PECL pecl_http >= 0.23.0`*

Comment: +1, `http_build_query` beats `urlencode` most of the times. If a new parameter needs to be added it's just a new array entry - no crappy string fiddling.

Comment: really nice solution. btw, you really expect someone is going to say "it was me" :)

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: Thanks; And I anticipate that when someone down-votes an answer they pay attention to the orange notice and comment on why they did so. I guess I hold the community to too high a standard.

Comment: Very nice, I'd never heard of that.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP function `urlencode()`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want the value of URL to be url http://foo2.com?thing=blah. What you need to do is use urlencode() to encode that value to be safe to include in a url.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [urlencode](http://us.php.net/urlencode) like so:

```
$url = 'http://foo.com?url=' . urlencode('http://foo2.com?thing=blah');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$par = urlencode('http://foo2.com?thing=blah');
$url = 'http://foo.com?url='.$par;
```

Comment: Won't down-vote you, but the `$link` (in your example) needs to be encoded so the `?` and `=` (among other characters) don't interfere with the parsing of this (and other) parameter(s).

Comment: @BradChristie Correct!! Thanks a lot for the feedback!
Can you please edit my answer and correct it? will be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

```
$url = urlencode("http://foo2.com?thing=blah");
header("location: http://www.example.com/?url=" . $url);
```

Comment: Not understood the question at all