# Character encoding of GET parameter in jsp form to php

Tags: php, jsp, tomcat

I´ve got a problem, related to pass a var through a form via $_GET

For instance if I put an accent ó, it transforms to %3F%3F, and if I put an echo on my php file the var $_GET['buscador'] appears like this ??.

I´ve been searching informatio about how to resolve this issue, and in some sites say that I have to write in my file server.xml this part of code:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
      maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
      enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
      connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
      useBodyEncodingForURI="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

But it is not working at all, anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, `GET` parameters are encoded to meet standards. You should decode parameters once you receive them :

```
$var = urldecode($_GET['buscador']);
```

Note : You should also encode your URL properly before making requests (when doing them by code). For Java you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java) and for PHP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662249/php-url-encoding-decoding).