# Java IllegalArgumentException Illegal character in query at index

Tags: java, php

I'm using the code below, which works fine when I use `http://stackoverflow.com/` .  When I change it to `http://www.sitetest.com/query.php?request=how are you` My app throws an exception. It says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 46: http://www.sitetest.com/query.php?request=how %20are%20you?
```

What is the Illegal Character in there? I can't spot it.

```
  AsyncTask<String, String, String> result = new RequestTask().execute("http://www.sitetest.com/query.php?request=how are you"); 
        try { 
            this.textToSpeech(result.get().trim());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Interrupted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) { 
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

> ```
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 46: http://www.sitetest.com/query.php?request=how %20are%20you?
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at com.sitetest.chat.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:170)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at com.sitetest.chat.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
> 12-22 19:17:32.547: E/AndroidRuntime(20764):    ... 4 more
> ```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: You need to encode your url first. Check a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java

Comment: I don't know what makes what is there happening, but main reason of the error is that it has a space before the first %20. All spaces should be encoded to %20 and the result should be free of spaces. Look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them for reference.

Comment: I have tried url encoding but no lock. removing this ?request=how are you will make the program run

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have some whitespace character there which is not the regular 
space character (decimal 32). Also, it seems it is not URL encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You should have inside the `execute` sth like:

```
urlencode('http://www.sitetest.com/query.php?request=how are you')
```

So, complete code on that line:

```
AsyncTask<String, String, String> result = new RequestTask().execute(urlencode('http://www.sitetest.com/query.php?request=how are you'));
```

**My source:**

[PHP URL Encoding / Decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662249/php-url-encoding-decoding)

**Side note:**

*I don't have a php environment installed on my machine right now, the verifying of that function needs to be made by you. That's what I found.*