# special characters send with url

Tags: php, html, forms, get

How do i get the special characters from a form submit.
For example: a form got a `name="customer[firstname]".`

The url will be `customer%5Bfirstname%5D=Test.`

i've tried:

```
$firstName = $_GET['customer[firstname]'];
```

also the same with `urldecode, rawurldecode.`

Comment: Did you try `$_GET['customer']['firstname']` ?

Comment: Read This 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662249/php-url-encoding-decoding

Comment: %20 is space, %5B is '[' ,  %5D is ']' so your url have array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `[...]` in your name attributes you are creating an array that you can access on the server as:

```
$firstName = $_GET['customer']['firstname'];
```

And if you omit the value in the brackets, you get a numerical array:

```
name="customer[]"
```

Would become on the server:

```
// for example, you should really loop over `$_GET['customer']` instead...
$firstName = $_GET['customer'][0];
```

Answer (score -1):

This is about HTML entities.

Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php